# Translate postgres query to sequelize

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I am having trouble connecting relationships in sequelize.

```
SELECT * from actors 
JOIN "actorStatuses" 
   on "actorStatuses".actor_id = actors.id 
JOIN movies 
   on movies.id = "actorStatuses".actor_id 
WHERE movies.date = '7/8/2017';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go :

```
model.Actor.findAll({ // change model name as per yours
    include : [
        {
            model : model.ActorStatuses // change model name as per yours
            required : true ,
        },{
            model : model.Movies // change model name as per yours
            required : true ,
            where : { date : 'your_date' }
        }
    ]
});
```

This will create exact same query / result as you required.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but don't I see to define the relationships first?

Comment: Yes that's the obvious thing

Comment: Thank you so much.